# Fan stuck at 257 RPM Thinkpad Yoga S1 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, fan, temperature, fancontrol

I was thinking for some time that my laptop seems to be hotter than it's supposed to and I recently downloaded psensor to have a look at what's going on. It seems my fan is always stuck at 257 RPM whatever the load is.

The `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` also shows

```
status:     enabled
speed:      257
level:      1
```

And `cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/fan1_input` also shows 257 (it seems the previous code is for legacy reasons).

I have tried different tools to see what is wrong, `sensors-detect` (adds `coretemp` module to `/etc/modules`; then sensors show:

```
coretemp-isa-0000 
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +57.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +57.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +55.5°C  

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:         257 RPM
```

Finally, pwmconfig shows:

```
Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon2/device/pwm1           current value: 36
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 201: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
hwmon2/device/pwm1 stuck to 36
Manual control mode not supported, skipping hwmon2/device/pwm1.
There are no usable PWM outputs.
```

I did try to add a file `thinkpad_acpi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` with `options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1` (as advised [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed)) and then control manually fan speed with `echo level 2 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` (also tried it on `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/fan1_input` to directly set something different from 257) but nothing changes.

I don't think that I had noticed that with Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 nor 15.04 (I did a clearn install of 16.04) but I can't be 100% sure, when I booted with a live distro of 15.04, it still showed 257 RPM for the fan.

Any advise on what's up, what else can I try?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you create the  file as root?

Comment: I'm not sure what file you are talking about, if it's the thinkpad_acpi.conf, I created it using sudo; I don't think that I created any other fan.

Comment: Another info, but it seems Lenovo published a patch of the BIOS that shows: 

CHANGES IN THIS RELEASE
  Version 1.20

[Important updates]
  Nothing.
 
[New functions or enhancements]
- Added support for MXIC SPI flash part
- Updated Fan table
- Updated RC Code


[Problem fixes]
- Fixed an issue that Fan stops working even when temperature reaching trigger point.
- Fixed an issue that Fn Sticky key is not keep after system resume from S3.
- Fixed an issue that it cannot disable USB charge on S3 when disable AOU in "Lenovo settings".

Comment: I would update the BIOS as this sounds like your issue. Make sure you are plugged into the mains when you do this.

Comment: Well after the update, the fan seems to now be working. It's just odd that there are no direct ways in Linux to check fanspeed and/or change it (Psensor still displays 257 RPM even though it's sure now quicker). I was reluctant to update the BIOS as last time it almost bricked my laptop (had to use emergency reset) but this time, it went fine.

Comment: If this is important to you please specify the model number of the Thinkpad you are using and run sensors-detect again accepting all the defaults pasting the entire dialog into paste.ubuntu.com and putting a link into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved with update 1.20 of BIOS. Apparently it was a known issue (raised on Lenovo forum) that could occur with some combination of settings, etc.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to the BIOS fan fix! I'm on antergos (arch derivative) and had the same issue. I have been running this installation for about a year without any problems, but after a recent system update my fans just stopped working. I tried with both `thinkfan` and `pwmconfig` (with kernel parameter `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`) but nothing fixed the issue. It didn't occur to me that it could be the BIOS since the laptop has been running fine for so long and I haven't touched the BIOS settings, but updating the BIOS did the trick and it's all good now, thanks again!